# Доступ по FTP к сайту с истекшим сроком аренды доменного имени

Tags: ftp, dns

Я забыл продлить аренду доменного имени (использовал hostinger+freenom). В итоге я зарегистрировал другое, но на том сайте остались важные файлы, локальной копии которых у меня нет. Пользовался FileZilla, но он стер нужные файлы, может NotePad++ куда-нибудь сохраняет?

Доступ к бд я получил, значит файлы все еще на месте. Что мне делать (письмо уже писал)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для доступа к сайту по FTP можно использовать не только доменное имя, но и IP, который можно найти в панели управления сайтом (в данном случае).